# Accessing locale in nextJS 14 App Directory

Tags: next.js, locale, router, payload

Could someone please guide how to access locale information in a server-side rendered page in Next.js version 14 using App Directory?  I'm currently working on a project where I need to retrieve locale information on a server page, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Any assistance or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to our community. Perhaps you could find some help at this link? [nextjs-internationalization](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization)